# Keras Binary Classification Histogram - Showing accuracy in each input type

Tags: tensorflow, keras, histogram, visualization

I've created a model for a specific type of data and evaluated it on a test set with a relatively small set of possible inputs. I would like to create a histogram that shows accuracy across each input after some number of trials (the paper did 40).

Where should I look to learn how to do this? None of my googling has helped me.

I am not entirely sure what type of code could even try to push this forward. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get accuracies from your Model and store them in the form of an array.You can use the following simple code for that purpose:

```
accuracies = []

for i in range(num_trials):
    predicted_labels = model.predict(test_data)
    accuracy = np.mean(predicted_labels == true_labels)
    accuracies.append(accuracy)
```

Then, You can use matplotlib library in python to get accuracy shown in the form of histogram.

```
plt.hist(accuracies, bins=np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1), edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Accuracy Histogram')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1))
plt.show()
```

Hope this will solve your problem. For video demonstrations you can search on Youtube about matplotlib to get more styels etc.

Comment: Ah! Great! Practicing on 1 single trial, and getting errors I'm not sure how to handle. Where you say "test_data", do you mean the full test set including labels, or just the features? Either way I get (very different) errors.

Comment: Yes I was referring to full test set. I mean data set will be one but tests will be performed multiple times using the loop I provided. If you have errors in even the first attempt there must be some issue in some other part of the code.